# Share/percent across a list of columns in a pandas agg

Tags: python, pandas

I have this kind of data frame

```py
dat = [{"date": datetime.date(2021,1,1), "c_id" : "a", "var1": 2, "var2":  1, "var3" : 10 },
       {"date": datetime.date(2021,1,1), "c_id" : "b", "var1": 2, "var2":  0, "var3" : 20 },
       {"date": datetime.date(2021,2,1), "c_id" : "a", "var1": 2, "var2":  1, "var3" : 30 },
       {"date": datetime.date(2021,2,1), "c_id" : "b", "var1": 2, "var2":  3, "var3" : 10 },
       {"date": datetime.date(2021,3,1), "c_id" : "a", "var1": 2, "var2":  1, "var3" : 30 },
       {"date": datetime.date(2021,3,1), "c_id" : "b", "var1": 2, "var2":  3, "var3" : 20 },
       ]

df = pd.DataFrame(dat)

>>> df
         date c_id  var1  var2  var3
0  2021-01-01    a     2     1    10
1  2021-01-01    b     2     0    20
2  2021-02-01    a     2     1    30
3  2021-02-01    b     2     3    10
4  2021-03-01    a     2     1    30
5  2021-03-01    b     2     3    20
```

I'd like to have the share of these 3 named variables per (date, c_id).  So for example...

```
>>> df
         date c_id  var1  var2  var3  var1_share var2_share var3_share
0  2021-01-01    a     2     1    10        0.15       0.07       0.76
1  2021-01-01    b     2     0    20        0.09       0.00       0.90
2  2021-02-01    a     2     1    30        0.06       0.03       0.90
3  2021-02-01    b     2     3    10        0.13       0.20       0.66
4  2021-03-01    a     2     1    30        0.06       0.03       0.90
5  2021-03-01    b     2     3    20        0.08       0.12       0.80
```

While I can do this in kind of a dumb way if I list these out individually...

```
>>> df.insert(5, "var1_share", df.apply(lambda x: x["var1"] / x[["var1", "var2", "var3"]].sum(), axis=1))
>>> df
         date c_id  var1  var2  var3  var1_share
0  2021-01-01    a     2     1    10    0.153846
1  2021-01-01    b     2     0    20    0.090909
2  2021-02-01    a     2     1    30    0.060606
3  2021-02-01    b     2     3    10    0.133333
4  2021-03-01    a     2     1    30    0.060606
5  2021-03-01    b     2     3    20    0.080000
```

What's the pandas magic for iterating this procedure over some list of valid columns, `mylist= ["var1", "var2", "var3"]`?  I suspect there is an apply that can do this in a one-liner?

Also, pandas experts, what would this operation be called across columns of a dataframe?  I'm sure this is common, but I'm not sure how I could have searched for it better.

Comment: Thanks, @Ben.T. I meant the operation of making a new column defined by some function `F( each c for c in columns, [columns])`

Comment: apologized, I misunderstood. So it would be apply a function to several columns. You could use `apply` with axis=0 if you have a function that can be applied to a column (series) at once. Like e.g. with your case, it could be `df[mylist].apply(lambda x: x.div(df[mylist].sum(axis=1), axis=0), axis=0)` where the `x` is representing one column in this case (not a row like with axis=1). Hope this is more what you are after :) but in your use case we can even vectorized to all columns at once as all the answer show here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
cols = pd.Index(['var1', 'var2', 'var3'])
df[cols+'_share'] = df[cols].div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
```

Output:

```
         date c_id  var1  var2  var3  var1_share  var2_share  var3_share
0  2021-01-01    a     2     1    10    0.153846    0.076923    0.769231
1  2021-01-01    b     2     0    20    0.090909    0.000000    0.909091
2  2021-02-01    a     2     1    30    0.060606    0.030303    0.909091
3  2021-02-01    b     2     3    10    0.133333    0.200000    0.666667
4  2021-03-01    a     2     1    30    0.060606    0.030303    0.909091
5  2021-03-01    b     2     3    20    0.080000    0.120000    0.800000
```

Let's use pandas intrinsic data alignment and `pd.DataFrame.div` with parameter `axis=0` and `pd.DataFrame.sum` with `axis=1`.

Comment: That's a great answer Scott :-)

Answer (score 5):

you can do it using `sum` along the columns.

```
mylist= ["var1", "var2", "var3"]
df[[f'{c}_share' for c in mylist]] = (df[mylist]/df[mylist].sum(axis=1).to_numpy()[:, None]).round(2)
print(df)
         date c_id  var1  var2  var3  var1_share  var2_share  var3_share
0  2021-01-01    a     2     1    10        0.15        0.08        0.77
1  2021-01-01    b     2     0    20        0.09        0.00        0.91
2  2021-02-01    a     2     1    30        0.06        0.03        0.91
3  2021-02-01    b     2     3    10        0.13        0.20        0.67
4  2021-03-01    a     2     1    30        0.06        0.03        0.91
5  2021-03-01    b     2     3    20        0.08        0.12        0.80
```

Answer (score 3):

Something from `numpy`

```
s = df.filter(like = 'var')
out = df.join(s/s.sum(axis=1).values[:,None],rsuffix = '_share')
out
Out[121]: 
         date c_id  var1  var2  var3  var1_share  var2_share  var3_share
0  2021-01-01    a     2     1    10    0.153846    0.076923    0.769231
1  2021-01-01    b     2     0    20    0.090909    0.000000    0.909091
2  2021-02-01    a     2     1    30    0.060606    0.030303    0.909091
3  2021-02-01    b     2     3    10    0.133333    0.200000    0.666667
4  2021-03-01    a     2     1    30    0.060606    0.030303    0.909091
5  2021-03-01    b     2     3    20    0.080000    0.120000    0.800000
```